# Defining properties on object or on object.prototype?

Tags: javascript, oop

I've recently seen JavaScript-code in which getter- and setter-methods where defined on the prototype-object on a constructor method.

For example:

```
Person.prototype.getFirstName = function() {
  return this.firstName;
}
```

Is this correct?

I mean: 
'this' points to the describer of the the object upon which the method was called.

What happens when I call ...

```
console.log(Person.getFirstName());
```

... without making an object prior?

Moreover:

Is there a general rule when to attach properties to the constructor-method and when to attach to the prototype-object?

From my view is attaching to the prototype correct if you don't necessarily have to create an object. Because the method doesn't use values of an object which have to set object-individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens when I call ...
>
> ```
> console.log(Person.getFirstName());
> ```
>
> ... without making an object prior?

You get an error, `Person` has no `getFirstName` property.

> Is there a general rule when to attach properties to the constructor-method and when to attach to the prototype-object?

Yes:

If you want the method to be available on objects created via the constructor function (e.g., on `obj` in `var obj = new Person()`), put the method on the constructor function's `prototype` object (shared) or assign the method to the object within the constructor by assigning to a property on `this` (not shared).

If you want the method to be available on the constructor function itself, the way some of the built-in JavaScript methods are (like `Date.parse` or `Object.create`), assign it to a property on the constructor:

```
Person.doSomething = function() {
    // ...
};
```

Those methods are not specific to objects created by the constructor (`this` within them is a reference to the constructor function itself, unless you do something to make it different).

If you're coming from a class-based language, a **very loose** analogy is that properties (including methods) you assign to the `prototype` object on the constructor or to `this` within the constructor are *instance properties*, and ones you assign to the constructor itself are *static properties*. It's a very loose analogy, but sometimes helpful.

Here's a full example in the old ES5 and earlier syntax:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.getName = function() {
        return name;
    };
}
Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    console.log("Hello, my name is " + this.getName());
};
Person.copy = function(other) {
    return new Person(other.getName());
};

// Usage example
var joe = new Person("Joe");
joe.sayHello();
console.log("joe's name is " + joe.getName());
var joeagain = Person.copy(joe);
joeagain.sayHello();
```

In the above:

- `getName` is available on *instances* created by `new Person`. It's created separately for each object and is not shared with other instances. It lets us get the person's name, which in this example is read-only.
- `sayHello` is available on *instances* created by `new Person` because they inherit it from their prototype, which is assigned to them by `new Person` from the `Person.prototype` property. It's shared between instances.
- `copy` is not available on instances (`joe.copy()` would be an error), it's a property on `Person` itself. In this case we use it to copy instances, but it could be for anything.

Comment: Awesome. You help me a lot. Thanks.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Prototypes get inherited by instantiating it with `new` keyword

**So the code**

```
var Person = function(){}
Person.prototype.getFirstName = function() {
  return this.firstName;
}

Person.prototype.firstName = "test";

console.log(Person.getFirstName()); // Throw Uncaught TypeError
```

**Correct method is:**

```
var Person2 = new Person()
Person2.getFirstName() // "test"
```

To test this Object:

so `Prototype` of `Person` is set to `this` Object of Person2 (Inheritance)

This is similar to `Class` as in Java or C# language.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'm not fond of adding a `getter` to the prototype if all you want is to access the instance values. You can already access those values via the instance:

```
function Person(name) {
   this.firstname = name;
}
Person.prototype.getFirstname = function() {
   return this.firstname;
}
var p = new Person('o-o');
console.log(p.firstname); //o-o
console.log(p.getFirstname()); //o-o
```

You could add a `getter` to the prototype to pass a different context:

```
var firstname = Person.prototype.getFirstname.call({firstname: 'other'});
console.log(firstname); // other
```

If so it'd make sense to add a `getter` to the prototype to add up some computation:

```
Person.prototype.getFirstname = function() {
   return new Date().toISOString + ': ' + this.firstname;
};
```

If that strategy suits your needs, you could orchestrate your code differently:

```
var common = {
  getValue = function(propName) {
     return new Date().toISOString() + ': ' + this[propName];
  }
};

function Person(name) {
   this.firstname = name;
}

$.extend(Person.prototype, common); //jQuery extend
var p = new Person('o-o');
console.log(p.firstname); //o-o
console.log(p.getValue('firstname')); //today: o-o
```

Extend your prototype with a versatile `common`: add logging information during development and drop those superfluous logging information in production.